# Ajax call works in simulator but not on device

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, devextreme

I've got a problem with an app I'm working on. the problem is that the app is working perfectly in simulator of Devextreme. If I try to run the app on my phone the AJAX call hits my error function. My code is as  following:

```
Application1.home = function(params) {
    var dataSource;
    var xml;
    CallService();

    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: baseAddress + 'getPickingOrders',
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            success: function(xmlObject) {
                xml = xmlObject
                console.log("succes ramt");
                dataSource = GetData(xml);
            },
            error: ErrorOccur
        });
        console.log(dataSource);
    }

    function ErrorOccur() {
        alert("Error ramt");
    }

    function GetData(xmlDoc) {
        var customerNumber = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('customerNumber');
        var getOrderNumber = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('orderNumber');
        var getDeliveryMethod = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('deliveryMethod');
        console.log("Datasource alerttt " + dataSource);
        console.log(customerNumber);
        console.log(getOrderNumber);
        console.log(getDeliveryMethod);

        var txt = [];
        var len = customerNumber.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            txt.push({
                customerNumber: customerNumber[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                getOrderNumber: getOrderNumber[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
                getDeliveryMethod: getDeliveryMethod[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            });
        }
        return txt;
    }

    var viewModel = {
        dataSource: dataSource,
        onRowClick: function(info) {
            info.rowElement.hasClass('clicked') ? info.rowElement.removeClass('clicked') : info.rowElement.addClass('clicked')
        },
    };

    return viewModel;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Have a look at the following changes from PhoneGap/DevExtreme: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T364109